# How can I send data using get method in php

Tags: php, api, curl

I want to send data using GET method but this code not working and I have an error massage:

> **The requested resource does not support http method 'POST'**

```
$url = "http://.....URL";
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
        array("Content-type: application/json"));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);
$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if ( $status != 201 ) {
    die("Error: call to URL $url failed with status $status, response $json_response, curl_error " . curl_error($curl) . ", curl_errno " . curl_errno($curl));
}
curl_close($curl);
$response = json_decode($json_response, true);
echo $response;
```

My data:

```
[
    {
        "id": 258,
        "value": 10,
        "Price": 560,
    },
    {
        "id": 259,
        "value": 5,
        "Price": 720,
    }
]
```

Comment: If you want to send a GET request, don't use CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS. Sending data via a GET request is usually done either through query parameters in the URL or through custom HTTP headers (although that's relatively uncommon).

Comment: @rickdenhaan I edited my question. I want send this data. How can I do that.

Comment: That's almost a valid JSON string. It's very unusual to send that via GET to a remote website, it's more common to use POST or PUT for that, so I'd suggest you check their documentation (or ask them) to see how they want to receive it so that they understand it. But in general, `$curl = curl_init($url . "?data=" . rawurlencode($content));` would send it as the "data" parameter, for example. The encoding is necessary because some characters (like `[` and `]`) have special meaning in a URL.

Comment: @rickdenhaan In postman I can send this data by `GET request > Body > raw and JSON` . But I don't know how can I send this data in php. Just this thing is mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: Huh. Interesting. Just dove into this a bit more, rather than just spouting off what I thought I knew. It looks like it's possible by setting `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST` to `"GET"`. Can you test that and see if it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We should setting the `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST` on `GET`.

```
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
      CURLOPT_URL => "URL",
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
      CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>$content,
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "Content-Type: application/json"
      ),
    ));
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
```

Answer (score 0):

The GET method use the URL for send the data 
example:

```
http://site/mypage.php?variable=value
http://site/index.php?show=donald
```

In the PHP Code you have to use this way for read the variable in the URL

```
<?php
echo 'Show ' . htmlspecialchars($_GET["show"]) . '!';
$show = $_GET["show"]; //store the value of show inside the variable show

if ( $show == "donald"){ // compare the variable show if the content are the same or not
   echo "Your choice is donald";
}else{
   echo "Your choice is other";
}

?>
```

Comment: Thank u for reply. I edited my question and I want send this data by php. How can I do that?

Comment: Use "parse_url" function to ask a url inside a php code.